# svg with concave top and bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have created an svg that draws a dynamic amount of horizontal and vertical lines in a grid fashion. What I want to accomplish now is to concave curve the top and bottom of the svg so that the lines naturally curve along with the coordinates of the svg while retaining those coordinates. So, if the viewBox is "0 0 100 100", after the concave curving of the entire svg, clicking the far-left or far-right at the very top would register a y value of 0, while clicking in the middle at the same level shouldn't register a click at all. To get y equaling 0 at x = 50, the mouse would have to be positioned however much lower to accommodate the curve.

I could of course programmatically curve every line, but that does not solve my issue of clicking and getting the appropriate coordinates to match up with the curving of the lines.

I thought of curving the borders of the container div, but the svg won't conform to that shape. I also thought of placing the svg inside a path which is inside an svg container, but if that is even possible, I don't see any examples of this occurring online.

I've also thought of using transforms, but none of them seemed suitable to this task, unless I have missed something.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are able to generate your transformation programmatically, why can't you pass the mouse coordinates to this algo too?

Comment: I am not currently curving the lines, so I would have to add in logic that manipulates the bezier curve progressively more the further from the center line both up and down. I can imagine how to accomplish that, and I'm sure I could take more time to come up with a method of calculating the mouse coordinate. I was hoping, since I'm already doing lots of calculations, that there would be a simpler way of accomplishing this specific task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. SVG supports only [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation), so you will have to find individual line descriptions and compute event locations in your non-affine space by programatic/mathematical means.
2. For confining event locations inside an area, [SVG clip paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#ClipPathElement) or [CSS clip paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/#the-clip-path) will on default prevent events being risen from the clipped parts of an element. If that does not help enough, you can further fine-tune the reaction with the [`pointer-events`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) property.